# Python object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python

this is the solution to a problem I'm working on (learning Python), but even the solution is giving me an error.

Here's the code:

```
def compute_deriv(poly):

    """
    Computes and returns the derivative of a polynomial function. If the
    derivative is 0, returns [0.0].

    Example:
    >>> poly = [-13.39, 0.0, 17.5, 3.0, 1.0]    # - 13.39 + 17.5x^2 + 3x^3 + x^4
    >>> print compute_deriv(poly)        # 35^x + 9x^2 + 4x^3
    [0.0, 35.0, 9.0, 4.0]

    poly: list of numbers, length > 0
    returns: list of numbers
    """

    poly_deriv = []
    if len(poly) < 2:
        return [0.0]
    for j in xrange(1, len(poly)):
        poly_deriv.append(float(j * poly[j]))
    return poly_deriv
```

This is the solution given to me, but when I use the following code to call the function:

```
poly1 = (-13.39)
print compute_deriv(poly1)
```

I get

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I've tried a couple different things inside the if statement (since this code only breaks when `len(poly)` is < 2;

I tried `poly_deriv.append(0.0)` and `return poly_deriv`, for example.

Comment: The document says you're supposed to call `poly` with a list. Try doing that.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+is+the+derivative+of+13.39

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a typo in the solution, and they intended it to be a one element collection.

```
poly1 = (-13.39,)
```

Or

```
poly1 = [-13.39]
```

The way they have it right now, it's a single float rather than a collection containing one float. `(-13.39)` is syntactically equivalent to just `-13.39` with no parentheses.

Comment: That was the problem.  When I tested the code I absent-mindedly made a single-value list (so, not actually a list) without a comma.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah! I always forget about the enforced delay there.

Comment: Wrong. The parenthesis are read as a parenthetical operation rather than a tuple. It's like the same thing with dictionaries and sets. See answer below.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, so we're in agreement then? `(-13.39)` is a parenthetical, `(-13.39,)` is a tuple. The comma is the important bit.

Comment: Yes, but there is no typo, just a misunderstanding of Python's operations.

Answer (score 4):

The line `poly1 = (-13.39)` isn't a tuple. Python reads this as a parenthetical operation not a so your variable is simply a number. Try a more explicit definition instead:

```
poly1 = tuple(-13.39)
```